# Change label on USB drive in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, usb

I am trying to write a program in Python that will rename a USB drive (from the standard "USB DISK" to my custom "MYDISK").

However, I can't find any way to do this neither in Python nor in OSX Terminal. (I figured, if I can make it work in Terminal, I can simply use `os.system("command")` in Python).

The USB drive is a FAT32 formatted flash drive on filesystem `/dev/disk2s1`, and it is by default mounted on `/Volumes/USB DISK`

What I have tried so far: (from http://techbu.com/2009/06/28/renaming-usb-drive-labels-in-linux)

```
sudo umount /Volumes/USB\ DISK            ## Works fine
sudo mlabel -i /dev/disk2s1 ::MYDISK      ## Command not found!
```

It seems that the "mlabel" command is not found in OSX Terminal. Is there an alternative?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/315220/how-to-rename-a-partition-in-os-x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [diskutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/diskutil)

```
sudo diskutil rename USB\ DISK MYDISK
```

Comment: Great! I figured I shouldn't unmount it first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then:

```
$ brew install mtools
```

This gives you `mlabel` and various other GNU utilities for working with MS-DOS.

Answer (score -4):

install it and every thing  done :D
https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mtools-Installation-on-Ubuntu-12.04

Comment: How does this help on OSX?